# Is it possible to transition from an initial tableview controller to a UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, splitview

I'm building a tutoring app, and need to transition from a tableview controller page, which contains all the tutors available to help, to a split view (with a messagesViewController on one side and a normal UIViewController on the other). How would I be able to do this?

I've already tried alternative ways of making the transition from one view to another view containing two side-by-side views, such as through subviews and container views, but I haven't had full success in that. Segues also don't seem to work in this scenario.

Right now, I'm using UISplitViewController, and have tried making the transition by using the following code in the tableview controller class:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) 
{

 let vc = splitViewController()
 navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

I'm getting this error in the output box:
`Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller`

So, is there any other way I can have a view controller transition to a split view controller? (In all the examples I've seen, the split view controller has been assigned the initial view controller in the storyboard, but in my case, I don't want it to be the initial view controller).